# How to use the filter method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am using filter method to get a selected item from an option list. But it gives me the following error:

> Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function.eslintarray-callback-return

My function is the following:

```
const getSelectValue = () => {
  const selectedList = get(state, `${name}`, []);
  if (isEmpty(selectedList) || isEmpty(options)) {
    return [];
  }
  const selectedSet = new Set(selectedList);
  return options.filter((item) => {
    if (item.value !== "Add type") return selectedSet.has(item.value);
  });
};
```

Anyone who can spot the missing thing here?

Answer (score 2):

The arrow function supplied as filter callback should always return some value by this linting rule. But here...

```
item => {
  if(item.value !=="Add type") {
    return selectedSet.has(item.value); 
  }
);
```

... there are no `return` statements if `if` condition is falsy; hence the error. You can fix this in many different ways; the most straightforward one is just adding explicit `return false;` at the end of the function. Another approach is combining two conditions:

```
item => {
  return item.value !=="Add type" && selectedSet.has(item.value) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return a value if statement is false (after if } enclosing bracket) and error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change like this :

```
const getSelectValue = () => {
        const selectedList = get(state, `${name}`, []);
        if (isEmpty(selectedList) || isEmpty(options)) {
            return [];
        }
        const selectedSet = new Set(selectedList);
        return options.filter(item => {
           
                return item.value !=="Add type" && selectedSet.has(item.value); 
        }  );
    };
```